# Outgoing HTML links broken with CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink

I know questions about broken links get asked all the time, however my issue seems a bit different, and none of the solutions have worked.

Right now none of the links to other websites in my nav section worked when clicked. It registers that they are there, and if you right click it and select "open in new tab" it works, but otherwise, nada. A few relative links (if thats the term for the href="#xxx" link to content on the page) to modal popups work fine though.

My HTML Code is listed below, as well as a Pastebin link to the CSS (so that I don't clutter up the box).

Removing the class="navigation" from the list tag seems to fix the link issue. Leaving the class on the tag but removing all the relevant CSS from the stylesheet, however, does not eliminate the issue and just removes the styling. I can't figure out why this would be the case.

I've tried setting the z-indices of my background, menu and nav to 1,2,3 (and 3,2,1 just for the hell of it) respectively so that they don't interfere, as recommended in other questions here, but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

CSS: http://pastebin.com/1KVTdBvF
Site: http://www.magratheamedia.com/npo

```
<div class="menu">  
<div class="container clearfix">

    <div id="logo" class="fleft">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div id="nav" class="fright">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li data-slide="1">Home</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.pn.npowned.net" target="_blank">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://pixelnations.wikia.com/wiki/New_Pacific_Order">Wiki</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gov" data-toggle="modal">Government</a></li>
            <li><a href="#charter" data-toggle="modal">Charter</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.pixelnations.net/index.php?id=16&nid=762">In-Game</a></li>
            <li><a href="#applicants" data-toggle="modal">Applicants</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://mibbit.com/#pnowned@irc.coldfront.net">IRC</a></li>


            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't CSS, it's your jQuery. This, in particular:

```
 links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});
```

When you find your links, like this:

```
var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
```

You have to somehow exclude the ones that go to external sites. Maybe by giving the modal links their own class name or something.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I hadn't even thought to check that for some reason. I'll play around with that and see what I can do. Thanks so much!